# Error "TypeError: ... is not a function" when trying to use a component function in template

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component as following and I am trying to provide my svg viewBox dimension dynamically, injected from my bootstrap in main.ts.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CircleComponent} from './circle.component';
import {Circles} from './circles.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css'],
    directives: [CircleComponent],
    providers: [Circles],    
    template: `
        <svg [attr.viewBox]="getViewBox()" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <svg:g my-circle *ngFor="#circle of circles.circles" [circle]="circle" />
        </svg>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    static parameters = [Circles, 'canvasWidth', 'canvasHeight'];

    constructor(circles: Circles, canvasWidth: Number, canvasHeight: Number) {
        this.circles = circles;
        this.width = canvasWidth;
        this.height = canvasHeight;
    }    

    function getViewBox(): String {
        return `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`;
    }
}
```

My main.ts

```
import {provide}        from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap}      from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent}   from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provide('canvasWidth', {useValue: 900}),
    provide('canvasHeight', {useValue: 300})
]);
```

And the exception I get

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.getViewBox is not a function in
>   [getViewBox() in AppComponent@1:13]

I'm not sure it's a good way to do this thing, but this information is needed elsewhere in my circles.service. One thing I don't like though is that I cannot  specify the Number type so I have to define *static parameters = [Circles, 'canvasWidth', 'canvasHeight'];* in AppComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `function` from your method declaration, It will look like below.

```
getViewBox(): String {
    return `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`;
}
```

---

Basically what happen behind the scene is when you write class method with `function`, transpiled JavaScript throw that `function` outside of that prototype function returned by the name of class. That's why it become unreachable.

In this case you would have get error at compile, if you are using `typescript` with better tool like Visual Studio/Web Strom.

```
export class App{
    function test(){
        console.log();
    }
}
```

**Transpiled As**

```
"use strict";
var App = (function () {
    function App() {
    }
    return App;
}());
exports.App = App;
function test() {
    console.log();
}
```

[**Code Link**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20class%20App%7B%0A%09function%20test()%7B%0A%09%09console.log()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: oh, I thought it was the way to define a function, you're right, it's working when I remove it...

Comment: I have another function in another class and if I remove the function keyword, that one is failing...

Comment: I read your full answer and I understand why my other case was falling, I had to use this.functionName() but I was using functionName() without this, then with the function keyword, It could be found some ways...

Comment: do you think it's a good way to inject the canvas width/height like I do or I should use another method? I should maybe create a new question

Comment: @JCorriveau I think lets open up new.. we can't really relate these both issue together.. Thanks :-)

Comment: you are mentionning visual studio, should I try Community edition or Code?